# Can a cashier refuse to service for tobacco because I was on the phone before the sell

Tags: constitutional-law

I had plenty of types of ids and I had no one in my car just was talking to my wife while heading home. He said that he can’t serve me because he doesn’t know if whoever I was on the phone with was a minor and never even checked my id. I’m 25 and I definitely dont look like I sell to kids

Comment: did you think there was a constitutional right to purchase smokes?

Answer (score 3):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

Yes, the retailer may refuse to sell.

There is generally no duty to sell. Making a product available for sale does not commit the retailer to sell. Until the retailer accepts the customer's offer to buy, the retailer has no obligation to provide the good. See generally *Pharmaceutical Society of Great Britain v Boots Cash Chemists (Southern) Ltd.* [1953] EWCA Civ 6.

Human rights codes only apply for acts in certain domains that discriminate on prohibited grounds. Having been on a phone is not a prohibited ground of discrimination.

The constitutional rights guaranteed in the *Canadian Charter of Rights and Freedoms* apply only against the government.

Answer (score 2):

At least in the US, if a store is private property, an owner or employee (agent of the owner) may refuse service to any person she/he chooses, provided that the refusal of service is not for a reason forbidden by applicable anti-discrimination law, such as banning all people of a particular race or religion. The idea that they didn't verify your age or check your ID isn't relevant; the bottom line is if the store is private property. There is no "constitutional right" to be on private property, nor an obligation for a business to serve you.

Comment: "There is no "constitutional right" to be on private property" Not always, see [Pruneyard Shopping Center v. Robins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pruneyard_Shopping_Center_v._Robins), where the state constitution grants access to private property open to the public to exercise First Amendment rights.